# syslog-ng 2.09 threaded() syntax

Tags: multithreading, syslog-ng, sles

Sles 11 SP 4
syslog-ng-2.0.9-27.34.39.2 - does threaded() even work on this version?

I'm trying to enable multithreading but running into a syntax error when adding the threaded() into the options {} stanza .. Line 16 is the threaded() .. I've tried a few things but nothing is working. Any advice would help? Thank You ~ Sean

=========== syslog-ng.conf ==================

```
options {
        create_dirs(yes);
        keep_hostname(yes);
        log_fetch_limit(100);
        flush_lines(100);
        use_dns(no);
        threaded(yes);
};
```

============== error ==============
Error parsing main, syntax error, unexpected LL_IDENTIFIER, expecting '}' in /opt/syslog-ng/etc/syslog-ng.conf at line 16, column 2:

```
    threaded();
    ^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syslog-ng version is too old, multithreading was introduced around version 3.3. You can find a [list of newer packages at the syslog-ng website](https://syslog-ng.org/3rd-party-binaries/), and detailed instructions on [how to install recent syslog-ng version on SLES](https://www.balabit.com/blog/installing-latest-syslog-ng-on-rhel-and-other-rpm-distributions/).

Regards, 
Robert